# Who first proved that the dimension of a vector space is unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, ho.history-overview, vector-spaces

every vector space is known to have a basis (assuming the axiom of choice). This is attributed to Georg Hamel (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Hamel). Moreover, any two bases have the same cardinality. In the finite dimensional case this is often proved by the Steinitz exchange lemma. An interesting note on the history of this lemma can be found [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=mAv_dofqXpYC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=steinitz+linear+algebra+vector&source=bl&ots=lxyLkGU_tk&sig=hCJi6yvxza9817NZToYG13iuTv0&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ZwVlT9aKFsLZsgabkuzgBQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=steinitz%2520linear%2520algebra%2520vector&f=false). In particular, the author points out that the exchange lemma isn't originally due to Steinitz but was published already by Grassmann in 1862.

However, my question is: Who has at first proved (or published a proof of) the uniqueness of  dimension in the general case ?

I checked Hamel's paper (an online link to this paper is included in the wikipedia article), but he only proves the existence of a basis without discussing its cardinality.

Comment: Your question is about "Cardinality of the basis ..." or "Size of the basis ...", $\hspace{2 in}$ although your title would also be interesting. $\:$

Comment: My question is about the fact that any two bases have the same cardinality. 

Comment: Interesting question.  Somehow in the typical linear algebra class the  
uniqueness of the size of a basis is only proved for finitely generated vector space.  This due to the fact that at that level students don't know enough set theory for the general case.
And once we teach them the set theory, we usually say "everything goes through just as in the finite dimensional case", which is true, of course.  Maybe this is how history went:  The infinite dimensional case was always regarded as obvious once you know the finite dimensional case and enough set theory.

Comment: Isn't the infinite case much easier than the finite case (and in fact almost trivial)? Given two sets $A,B$ of basis elements just write each element of $A$ in terms of finitely many elements in $B$, and since this spans we must use every element of $B$ somewhere, so $B$ is a union of finite sets indexed by $A$, hence if they're both infinite, $|B| \leq |A|$. Similarly $|A| \leq |B|$. 

Maybe when set theory wasn't well-developed this proof was less obvious, but to me it seems likely that it's a sufficiently easy result it might not have been formally published but just remarked somewhere.

Comment: The reference in Howard-Rubin points to L. Löwig who published a proof in this paper: matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm5/sm513.pdf. Also, note that it already follows from the Boolean primer ideal theorem (or ultrafilter lemma) which is strictly weaker than the full axiom of choice

Comment: @godelian: The reference on Löwig's paper looks very good. Thank you very much. 

Comment: The title of this question still should be changed, as far as I can tell...

Comment: @Yemon: Yes, of course it should be "cardinality" instead of "dimension". But because the question is answered by godelian's comment, I don't want to pop up the question on MO's list of questions by doing the change. 

Answer (score 7):

Since this has already been bumped, I'll copy godelian's reference into an answer:

> Löwig, H. "Über die Dimension linearer Räume." *Studia Mathematica*, 5(1):18-23, 1934. http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm5/sm513.pdf.